# How to optimize SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am copying data from one table to another table. While copying I am doing some calculation to modify one column.

SQL Server query:

```
 INSERT INTO rat_proj_duration_map_2
  SELECT
    r.*,
    r.hour_val / (CASE
      WHEN week_val = 1 AND
        (SELECT TOP 1
          hrswk
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.username = us.username
        WHERE calwk = 2
        AND r.uid = u.uid
        AND yr = 2016)
        > 0 THEN (SELECT TOP 1
          hrswk
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.username = us.username
        WHERE calwk = 2
        AND r.uid = u.uid
        AND yr = 2016)
      WHEN (SELECT
          hrswk
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.username = us.username
        WHERE r.week_val = us.calwk
        AND r.uid = u.uid
        AND yr = 2016)
        < 1 AND
        (SELECT
          MAX(hrswk)
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.username = us.username
        WHERE r.uid = u.uid
        AND yr = 2016)
        > 0 THEN (SELECT
          MAX(hrswk)
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.username = us.username
        WHERE r.uid = u.uid
        AND yr = 2016)
      WHEN (SELECT
          COUNT(*)
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.username = us.username
        WHERE r.uid = u.uid
        AND yr = 2016)
        <= 0 THEN 1
      ELSE (SELECT
          hrswk
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.username = us.username
        WHERE r.week_val = us.calwk
        AND r.uid = u.uid
        AND yr = 2016)
    END) * 100 AS percentage_val
  FROM rat_proj_duration_map r
```

When I run this query I getting time out issue.

> TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]

SQL Server is not in my hand to increase time out value.

Is it possible to optimize my SQL query?

Comment: add execution plan to question: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1856/sql-server-query-execution-plans-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Answer (score 0):

The subqueries in your case clause seem to be essentially the same. You could simplify the whole command by defining a grouped version (`... where yr=2016 group by u.uid`) of this subquery (preferrably as a common table expression) and then work with that. This could potentially save a lot of redundant operations.

The following might work (have not tested it):

```
;WITH usrall as (
 SELECT u.uid ui,  hrswk hw, r.week wk, us.calwk cw 
 FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us 
 INNER JOIN users u on u.username=us.username  
 WHERE r.uid=u.uid and yr=2016
),   usrgrp as (
 SELECT ui gui, MAX(hrswk) ghw, count(*) gcnt FROM usrall group by ui
),   denom  as (
 SELECT gui dui, COALESCE( MAX(w2.hw), MAX(wkwc.hw), MAX(gwh) ) dnm
 FROM usrgrp 
 LEFT JOIN usrall w2   ON   w2.ui=gui AND w2.cw=2 AND w2.hw>0 
 LEFT JOIN usrall wkcw ON wkcw.ui=gui AND wkcw.wk=wkcw.cw AND wkwc.hw<1
 GROUP BY gui
)        
SELECT r.*, r.hour_val / d.dnm
FROM rat_proj_duration_map r
INNER JOIN denom d ON d.dui=u.uid
```

Essentially I have tried (I hope it works :-/) to replace the case construct by a `COALESCE()` function that checks the three possible calculated values one after the other. The first non-null value is accepted.

As I said: I have not tested it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this query is logically correct? You have several `TOP 1`s without specific `ORDER BY`, scalar comparison of subselect without `TOP` (which, I assume, may return more than one row if you are using `top` in other subselects with same source).

And yes - this query can be optimized. You can obtain all the values you need with a single subselect statement and avoid multiple execution of same subselects for each row of rat_proj_duration_map which you are having now:

```
INSERT INTO rat_proj_duration_map_2 
    SELECT 
        r.*,
        r.hour_val / (CASE
                              WHEN week_val = 1 AND us.min_hrswk_2 > 0 
                                 THEN us.min_hrswk_2
                              WHEN us.min_hrswk_week_val <1
                                AND max_hrswk > 0 
                                 THEN max_hrswk
                              WHEN us.cnt <= 0 
                                 THEN 1
                              ELSE min_hrswk_week_val
                           END) * 100 as percentage_val
    FROM  
        rat_proj_duration_map r
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
          count(*) as cnt,
          MIN(CASE WHEN calcw = 2 THEN hrswk END) as min_hrswk_2,
          MIN(CASE WHEN calcw = r.week_val THEN hrswk END) as min_hrswk_week_val,
          MAX(hrswk) as max_hrswk
        FROM UserProfileRATinterface_view us
        inner join  users u on u.username=us.username 
        WHERE r.uid=u.uid and yr=2016
    ) us
```

But I can't be sure if original logic is correct. And the idea of that case to me looks like this:

```
...
    r.hour_val / COALESCE(NULLIF(us.min_hrswk_2, 0), 
         NULLIF(us.min_hrswk_week_val, 0), NULLIF(max_hrswk, 0), 1)
...
```